# Converting an OpenCV program into a Module reduces frame rate drastically

Tags: python, opencv, pose-estimation

I wrote a code for pose estimation using OpenCV and mediapipe library. The program was working well and I was getting around 30-35 fps. When I tried to convert the same program to a module so that I can use it easily in future for different projects, the fps of the new code(module) reduced drastically to 3-4 fps.
My original Program:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
pTime = 0
cTime = 0

mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mpPose.Pose()  
   
while True:
    success, img1 = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img1, 1)  

    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = pose.process(imgRGB)

    if results.pose_landmarks:
        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

        for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
            h, w, c = img.shape
            cx, cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
            cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1/(cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (10, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 8), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Live Feed", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

My attempt at converting it into a module :

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class poseDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, upBody=False, smooth=True, detectionCon = 0.5, trackingCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.upBody = upBody
        self.smooth = smooth
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackingCon = trackingCon

        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
        self.pose =self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.upBody, self.smooth, self.detectionCon, self.trackingCon)         

    def findPose(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)

        if self.results.pose_landmarks:
            if draw:
                 self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, self.results.pose_landmarks, self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
    return img

    def findPosition(self, img, draw=True):
        lmList = []
        if self.results.pose_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(self.results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        return lmList

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0

    while True:
        success, img1 = cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img1, 1)

        detector = poseDetector()
        img = detector.findPose(img) 
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1/(cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (10, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 8), 2)

        cv2.imshow("Live Feed", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

According to me , both the code should have been working in the same manner, but they are not. Can anyone tell where am I making mistake ?

Comment: you should work on a "minimal reproducible example" for your post. this question is not generally useful because it amounts to simple programming mistakes that should have been found with debugging or at most profiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place `detector = poseDetector()` to be before the `while True:`:

```
detector = poseDetector()

while True:
    success, img1 = cap.read()
    ...
```

---

Your "module" implementation creates a new `poseDetector` object every iteration of the main loop.
Each execution of `detector = poseDetector()` includes a call to `poseDetector.__init__` that calls `self.pose =self.mpPose.Pose`...
There is a lot of overhead...

```
while True:
    success, img1 = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img1, 1)

    detector = poseDetector()
    ...
```

---

In your original ("non-module") implementation, you are executing `pose = mpPose.Pose()` only once (before the loop).

```
pose = mpPose.Pose()  
   
while True:
    success, img1 = cap.read()
    ...
```

---

I have tested your code before and after moving `detector = poseDetector()` outside the loop.
After moving the line above the loop, the frame rate is the same as the "non-module" implementation.